# I can't select Microsoft Git Provider

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

I was confused, when I click and select Microsoft Git Provider, the select option does not accept my selection, but if I select other option it's fine, I need to select Microsoft Git Provider to fix my error in team explorer. I tried to clear cache and restart but still the problem was there, I am using Visual Studio community 2015.

[Please check Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVFh3.png)

Any idea?

Comment: AFAICT, the git provider is the only sane provider that is automatically selected if and only if the project/solution are actually within git work directory. Do you have up-to-date git installed and is the project inside git checkout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I fixed, just update Visual Studio. under tools/Extension and Updates/ visual studio update.